# How can i format vue beautiful in visual studio code like sublime text?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext

> How can I format .vue in visual studio code as nice as sublime text?

**When I use vetur format code, it looks like this:**:

[image]

**But I want to like this:**:
[image]